# Prove $1! + 2! + . . . + n! < (n + 1)!$ using mathematical induction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, factorial

$1! + 2! + . . . + n! < (n + 1)!$

This question has left me stumped for quite some time. I am not sure how to approach it. (I am really bad at induction).

Answer (score 2):

$
1! + 2! + \cdots + n! \le n! + n! + \cdots + n! = n\cdot n! < (n+1)\cdot n! = (n + 1)!
$